# How to call a function or method inside its own class in php?

Tags: php, function, oop, methods

I declare my class in PHP and several functions inside. I need to call one of this functions inside another function but I got the error that this function is undefined. This is what I have:

```
<?php
class A{

 function b($msg){
   return $msg;
 }

 function c(){
   $m = b('Mesage');
   echo $m;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use class functions using `$this`

```
<?php
    class A{

     function b($msg){
       return $msg;
     }

     function c(){
       $m = $this->b('Mesage');
       echo $m;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

This is [basic OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php). You use the `$this` keyword to refer to any properties and methods of the class:

```
<?php
class A{

 function b($msg){
   return $msg;
 }

 function c(){
   $m = $this->b('Mesage');
   echo $m;
 }
}
```

I would recommend cleaning up this code and setting the [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) of your methods (e.e. private, protected, and public)

```
<?php
class A{

 protected function b($msg){
   return $msg;
 }

 public function c(){
   $m = $this->b('Mesage');
   echo $m;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$this` to refer to the current object

`$this->` inside of an object, or self:: in a static context (either for or from a static method).

Answer (score 0):

To call functions within the current class you need to use `$this`, this keyword is used for non-static function members.

Also just a quick tip if the functions being called will only be used within the class set a visibility of private

```
private function myfunc(){}
```

If you going to call it from outside the class then leave it as it is. If you don't declare the visibility of a member function in PHP, it is public by default. It is good practice to set the visibility for any member function you write.

```
public function myfunc(){}
```

Or protected if this class is going to be inherited by another, and you want only the child class to have those functions.

```
protected function myfunc(){}
```